# Twilio Caller ID (outgoing) show extension

Tags: twilio

How do i set up twilio where it shows an extension after sending the call to my phone? Example: the caller id that shows up from the caller to my phone is, "123-456-7890" - is there any way to make that number show up as "123-456-7890X" or anything after so that i know its coming from twilio.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't add anything to the caller ID like that, but you can do something else to alert you that an incoming call is from Twilio.

When you set up your [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to [forward the call](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/set-up-an-sms-forwarding-number-in-5-minutes-with-twilio.html), you can set [the `url` attribute on the `<Number>` element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url). You can point this URL at some more TwiML that will be played before the calls are connected. This is called a [call whisper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper) and you can use it to tell yourself that the call is coming from Twilio before you connect with the caller.

Let me know if that helps at all.